# Python stack class within another class for postfix/infix

Tags: python, class, data-structures, stack, postfix-mta

Currently working on a program that converts postfix notation to infix and vice versa (using stacks) when given input and direction (0 or 1, for either infix or postfix depending on what the user enters.)

I am required to make the `stack` class a private field of the `expression` class. This part confuses me.

How exactly is this done when a class is within a class? A skeleton structure would be helpful as I am familiar with the code to convert.

```
class Expression:
    def __init__(self, input, direction):
        self._infix
        self._postfix

        self._input = input
        self._direction = direction
        
    def in_to_post(self):
    def post_to_in(self):
    def evaluate(self):
```

Comment: for a stack you can use python's built-in list data type (append to push, pop to pop).  to make it "private" prepend a single underscore to the class member name.  (this is convention in python; not pure private in the C++/Java sense)

Comment: Could you give an example? Do I add something to Expressions __init__, then make a _Stack outside of expression?

Comment: in the __init__ function add and initialize a member variable:   self._stack = []
if you're required to use a custom class:  self._stack = MyStack()

Comment: And then outside of the expression class, write a MyStack class?

Comment: ^^ yes, which implements push and pop. it could be a thin wrapper around python's list type